# How to customize name, length and value of a discriminator column with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, maxlength, discriminator, tph

I try to use EF6 with an existing database I must be compatible with.
The database has been generated by nHibernate and some tables use the table-per-hierarchy (TPH) inheritance model.

Discriminator columns are named `Category` (instead of `Discriminator`) and have an SQL length of 255 (instead of 128). Values are also different from what EF would generate.

How can I configure EF to use the existing columns (name, size and values)?

I tried to define a custom convention:

```
protected class DiscriminatorRenamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)
    {
        if (property.Name == "Discriminator")
        {
            property.Name = "Category";
            property.MaxLength = 255;
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityA>().Map(x => x.Requires("Category").HasValue("CatA"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityB>().Map(x => x.Requires("Category").HasValue("CatB"));
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<DiscriminatorRenamingConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

This generates a column named `Category` but with a length of 128, whatever the order of instructions in the `OnModelCreating` method. Specifying category values seems to overwrite `MaxLength`.

Comment: What is max length here. It is property for Name with total 255 length for  column(Name) or something else? @daltonwide

Comment: I use MaxLength to map the SQL column as nvarchar(255)

Comment: so i am providing in answer may be this could fix it, because code can not be written in comment.@daltonwide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityA>().Map(x => x.Requires("Category").HasValue("CatA"));
```

you specify the name of the discriminator to be "Category", so this

```
if (property.Name == "Discriminator")
```

will evaluate to `false`, hence the `MaxLength` will be the EF default.

To get the desired behavior, use `Requires("Discriminator")` and let the convention do the rest.

Comment: No, the 'DiscriminatorRenamingConvention' works fine by itself. The discriminator column is correctly renamed to 'Category'. It's only when I specify category values that the custom length reverts to 128.

Comment: Well, why asking if you didn't try the answers. I always test before posting. Do what I said and see.

Comment: My apologies, it sounded illogical to me but you are right. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I agree it's not so intuitive :)